# Triple question mark in Kotlin?

Tags: scala, kotlin

In Scala you can delay the implementation with triple question mark as:

```
def doSomething(s: String): Int = ???
```

Does Kotlin support such as feature?

Comment: Note that `???` is simply a method like any other method. There is nothing special about it. So, asking "Does Kotlin support such a feature" is essentially asking "does Kotlin support methods or functions or procedures or subroutines". Now, I haven't used Kotlin, but I strongly suspect the answer is "Yes".

Comment: [`scala.Predef.???`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#???:Nothing) is *literally* just: [`def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L343-L347).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [`TODO`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-t-o-d-o.html) function that does something similar. You can either call it with a string that gives a reason for it being unimplemented, or you can just say `TODO()` with no arguments. The return type is `Nothing`, but it will throw a `NotImplementedError` (just like `???` in Scala), as Jörg W Mittag pointed out.

Comment: "The return type is `Nothing`, but it will throw a `NotImplementedError`." – And that is *exactly* what [`scala.Predef.???`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#???:Nothing) does as well. Here's the code: [`def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L343-L347). I'm pretty sure that one inspired the other.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yeah, I'll note that in my answer. I think Scala inspired the Kotlin version